# Green tick missing next to answer

Tags: support, answers, comments, accepted-answer

Somebody has answered a question I asked, and I want to mark it as the answer. I've followed the instructions on [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), but I don't have the green tick next to the answer (or anywhere else), just an upvote icon and a flag this comment icon.

[image]

Is there an issue with the site/my permissions, or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> and a flag this comment icon

Exactly. That's a comment. You can't mark it as accepted - you can, however, request that user (@by @tagging @them) to write an answer, and if that isn't written within a reasonable time (2 days to allow for time zones) then just write one yourself and accept it. You won't get rep from the accept, but you will from any upvotes you get on the answer.

Also, from the image it looks like the comment is just a link - if you decide to write the answer please make sure to also explain how it helped you and make it useful for others, in case the link will die in the future.

(Credit to [Adinia](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/469983/adinia) for the above paragraph.)

Comment: Also, from the image it looks like the comment is just a link - if you decide to write the answer please make sure to also explain how it helped you and make it useful for others, in case the link will die in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can see where the misunderstanding arose.

Just as feedback, I understand that stack overflow is making the distinction between answers and comments. However, as an end user these two aren't mutually exclusive concepts in my head - a comment can also be an answer, if it answers a question.

Comment: No, the reason these sites make that distinction is that comments are treated as "second class citizens" and if the conversation gets too "noisy", comments will get cleared out. You don't want a good "answer" buried in a comment that might get wiped out at any time.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, now that you explain the reasons for those decisions.

Comment: Worth noting that while Stack Overflow doesn't really enforce it, some other sites in the Stack Exchange network have a strict rule against answering in comments partly to avoid this confusion.