# How to mark a question as answered should be made clearer for newbies

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

I'm new to Stack Overflow and am following the guidelines listed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

It tells you to "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.".

Asking my first question, I got many replies, and I wanted to mark one as the correct answer, but I really struggled. After a fair bit of searching I realised everyone was commenting their answers, but not providing any actual answers!

I propose a simple change to the page, letting you know how to answer, just to let you know that comments may appear above answers which are listed below.

Comment: But you took the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) wherein differences between *answers* and *comments* are also shown.

Comment: Aren't you asking for it to be clearer how to *answer*, not to mark it as answered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I'm not adverse in helping new users with on-boarding to the Stack Exchange Network and its Q/A format I'm not convinced that adding a text that explains where to find answers will be helpful for lots of visitors.

Strangely enough more users seem to struggle: [Green tick missing next to answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387126/green-tick-missing-next-to-answer)

On the question page itself the [Answers do have an heading with the text "1 Answer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySas4.png) to mark where the question and their comments end. I think that should suffice to indicate where the answers are. Those basic UI elements are also featured in the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

If anything, I rather seek for a solution that makes it clear on the Q/A page where the answers are and which call to action for an OP should be prevalent based on the current state their post is in.

I prefer to not add more text to something that is doomed to be considered an information overload already.